# Pull metadata about all documents in all subsites

Tags: api, file-metadata

ok so what im looking for is to get metadata about every single document from a site down including all subsites.

I'm new to sharepoint and am finding it rather confusing. I have found several examples of doing this via the APIs but my question is what is the easiest way to get that data?

Is there some magical reporting feature i don't know about or should i just roll up my sleeves and get up to my armpits in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such out of the box feature in SharePoint, but you can check [Sharegate Reporting feature](https://en.share-gate.com/reporting).